# How to e2e test handsontable with selenium

Tags: selenium, handsontable, e2e-testing

We're building an app that has some handsontable tables.
We'd love to write an e2e test with selenium that simulates a user clicking on a cell and entering in data.

However, for the life of me, i can't figure out how to do this from a programmatic way in selenium (or even plain-old javascript for that matter)

Any pro tips or examples someone would like to share?

Comment: which is your prefer language, java, javascript, python?

Comment: javascript, ideally, but anything will do. I'm more interested in how to simulate mouse events to be able to enter in values at a certain cell

Answer (score 0):

I give workable code to simply input type into the 5th cell of 1st row.  I use [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) as automation framework, and test on the handsontable example from [here](https://handsontable.com/examples?manual-resize&manual-move&conditional-formatting&context-menu&filters&dropdown-menu&headers).

```
var url = 'https://handsontable.com/examples?' + 
    'manual-resize&manual-move&conditional-formatting&' +
    'context-menu&filters&dropdown-menu&headers';

describe('handsontable', function(){

    it('input text into cell', function(){

        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get(url);
        browser.sleep(3000);

        var css = '.ht_master.handsontable table > tbody tr:nth-child(1) *:nth-child(5)';
        var cell = element(by.css(css));

        browser.actions().mouseMove(cell).click().doubleClick().perform();

        browser.sleep(2000);

        element(by.css('.handsontableInputHolder:not([style*="-9999"]) > textarea')).clear().sendKeys('Test')

        browser.sleep(3000);

    })
})
```